# Wordpress // Custom Post Type and taxonomy URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

In WP, I have the following setup :

2 Custom Post Type :

- Post type 1
- Post type 2

1 Custom Taxonomy :

- Category

The custom taxonomy Category is attached to the custom Post type 1 and custom Post type 2.

By default, my URLs are :

[www.example.com/category/term](http://www.example.com/category/term)

I'd like to move to the following url structure :

[www.example.com/post-type/category/term](http://www.example.com/post-type/category/term)

or even better :

[www.example.com/post-type/term](http://www.example.com/post-type/term)

What is the best way to achieve this ? I've tried to use Custom Rewrite Slug (using for example : post-type-1/category) but it doesn't work for post-type-2 then...

Thanks a lot

PS: I am using CPT UI extension for creating CPT and Taxonomies

Comment: There might be other (and possibly better) options, but I had a problem with custom permalinks on a personal website and I ended up using the plug-in "Custom Permalinks" which now gives me full control over the permalink for each post I make.

Comment: Hi, I am using Custom Permalinks, however it doesn't allow to remove the cpt slug...